# What does sentiment = model.predict(twt,batch_size=1,verbose = 2)[0] means?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I am predicting the sentiment using Keras . I do not understand what this code segment means.

```
 sentiment = model.predict(twt,batch_size=1,verbose = 2)[0]
 print (sentiment)
 print (np.argmax(sentiment))
```

I get the result as,

```
[0.18970804 0.81029195]
1
```

I am predicting a tweet. It is a positive sentiment tweet. And twt is the tweet. For the sentiment i get two values and out of two i get the sentiment as 1. Which is positive. How does it get it?
Can anyone explain. 
Thank you in advance

Comment: What exactly is your question? The meaning of the output or the code?

Comment: A bit complicated to say without context. I would say that you are classifying whether the sentiment in your (tweet?) belongs to one class or another. In this case, your network predicted that your `twt` belongs to the second class.

Comment: Yeah what you are basically doing is providing the neural network with the input in twt. After that the code prints the probabilities for each class. In your example the probability that the input belongs to sentiment 0 was 0.18 and that it belongs to 1 was 0.81. Usually you are just interested in the class with the highest probability. That's the reason for the argmax in the last print. There it prints the class that the neural network "predicted" (which is the largest probability if you look at all classes)

Comment: I am predicting a tweet. It is a positive sentiment tweet. And twt is the tweet. For the sentiment i get two values and out of two i get the sentiment as 1. Which is positive. How does it get it? @Syrius

Comment: When you trained your model you defined two outputs. Output 0 is the output with negative sentiments, output 1 the output with positive sentiments (I guess that from your description. It could also be the other way around). If you now present a tweet that should be predicted to the neural network, it will present you with probabilities that the tweet belongs to class x at each output. This means in this specific example the probability that it is a negative sentiment would be 0.18 (if negative corresponds to output 0) and 0.81 that it is positive.

Comment: its a basic syntax question and provides no value to anyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two values give the probability of sentiment being 0 and sentiment being 1. Both the probabilities add to 1. In this case, as the probability of sentiment being 1 is greater than 1, the tweet is classified as positive sentiment.